# Can I use multiple logging libraries in a Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I would like to use the built-in Logger for some actions and log4r for some others...  [the Guides explain that](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html) the logger is set in application-level config files, for example:

```
Rails.logger = Logger.new(STDOUT)
Rails.logger = Log4r::Logger.new("Application Log")
```

Is there a way to set this at the controller or model level?

Comment: [Maybe writing a custom logger](http://dennisbloete.de/blog/silencing-the-rails-log-on-a-per-action-basis/) - Logger for some actions, Log4r for others, and silencing it for the rest - will help you.

Comment: I don't see how this can work if the CustomLogger class is deriving from either Logger or log4r.  This method simply overrides a method in the default Logger class.

Comment: I ended up using this idea...  make an answer and I'll accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always code a [custom logger](http://dennisreimann.de/blog/silencing-the-rails-log-on-a-per-action-basis/):

- send everything to `Logger` for some actions;
- send everything to `Log4r` for other actions;
- and silence logging for everything else;